# bash path clean output

Tags: bash, curl, xpath

I'm executing the following command in a bash script

```
curl --silent "https://$URL” | xpath "//connections/ip/text()"
```

It's working great, but the output includes additional information i.e.

```
Found 1 nodes:
-- NODE --
192.123.234.11
```

How can I clean the output so I'm only getting the IP address?

Thanks

Comment: Which `xpath` utility are you using? I can't find it in the Arch Linux standard repositories.

Comment: `xpath` is installed by some perl library, probably the one for `libxml`.

Answer (score 1):

`xpath` lists this flag:

```
        -q              quiet. Only output the resulting PATH
```

Therefore, you can use:

```
curl --silent "https://$URL" | xpath -q -e "//connections/ip/text()"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use grep

```
curl --silent "https://$URL” | xpath "//connections/ip/text()" | grep "[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try piping to grep:

```
curl --silent "https://$URL” | xpath "//connections/ip/text()" | grep -oP "\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\"
```